# Local install of sqlite3-ruby

Tags: ruby, installation, sqlite3-ruby

On my current system i dont have root-access and i want to install sqlite3-ruby.
I can compile it and i know how to set custom install-folder, but how does my ruby-installation can recognize/find that installed gem for usage?

I tried prefix of my custom RUBYLIB-Folder but that didnt work either.

Any suggestions?

Thanks skully

Answer (score 0):

By default, if you don't have root access, RubyGems tries to install the gem in your home directory, within the ~/.gem directory.
Just type

```
$ gem install sqlite3-ruby
```